# Xcode crashes when I run my Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm running Xcode 4.6.1, with that latest SDKs, I can build the project just fine, but when I try to run it, it crashes.

Here is the beginning of the crash report.

```
Process:         Xcode [13573]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6.1 (2067)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2067000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 14581035
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [278]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-04-08 17:57:47.633 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          39613 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1751 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      DC5CB8D0-2A9C-75E6-5631-42D5362B172F

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H512
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFString alloc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4009ce3e0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff8ea76aee __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff867863f0 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8eb0d40a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in Core Foundation)
```

Code being built and compiled is from the template for the Command Line Tool in Xcode

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to show some code. But it looks like you are trying to call an invalid method or something similar. See the backtrace 2 - "...[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]..."

In order to figure out what's wrong, you will need to show some more code. Thanks!

Comment: If Xcode crashes, you should report it as a bug to Apple.

Comment: I'm using the code from the Command Line Tool template in Xcode. I didn't write any code.

Basically uses NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

Comment: Has this installation of Xcode *ever* worked??  The first thing to try is to "clean" the app.  Next, try creating a new app and see if it works.  Failing that, delete DerivedData.  And, failing that, completely delete and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @Josiah You've misread the question. His app / project is not crashing. Xcode itself is crashing. There is no code to show; he doesn't have the code to Xcode itself! (Well, if he does, I'd like to take him to lunch.)

Comment: @matt, Wow, sorry! That is pretty bad.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: If Xcode crahses, that's God's sign for you that you should start using clang from the command line instead.

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be a corrupt installation of Xcode and/or a system gone bad.

If you can open/build/run other projects, I would be surprised.  If so, this *may* be a case that the derived data folder is bunk.   Try deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` (assuming you've left it in the default location.

Also, have a look in Console.app and see if there are any disturbing messages.

Comment: If the console message is "I know where you live", be especially worried.

Comment: I still want to know what in the heck would cause a concrete subclass of NSString to refuse a message to +alloc.

Comment: A corrupt dyld cache could cause this.  So could a corrupt dylib or executable.  Or something mucking with the runtime.  But, yeah, something is seriously amiss.